# Image not appearing in certain browsers

Tags: html

I have this logo image in the top left of the page on http://universeapp.co

The image shows up in safari on my mac but it doesn't show up in google chrome or on the iPhone?

It was working earlier and now it doesn't.. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `http://universeapp.co/images/universe%20app%20icon.png` image is a PSD with a PNG file extension. You need to re-save it as a PNG file, rather than a Photoshop document with the PNG extension.

The reason the image appears in Safari is Safari has the ability to render PSD files. Most browsers do not and PSD's are rather large, so re-saving as PNG is important.

Answer (score 0):

The image is not available. re upload the image and try

see

http://universeapp.co/images/universe%20app%20icon.png